# How to open the two udp client socket with same local port

Tags: c, sockets, udp, udpclient, hole-punching

How to open two client socket with the same local port like java.
In Java we can mention the source port while creating DatagramPacket. 
I am trying to do UDP hole punching. Correct me if i done anything wrong.

I have added my code here.

```
void UDPClientConnect ( string IP , string Port ) 
{ 
    WSADATA wsa;


if ( WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0 )
{
    printf ( "startup failed %d\n" , WSAGetLastError() ) ;
    return ;
}
int reuse = 1 ; 
SOCKET s = socket ( AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP ) ;
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,(char*) &reuse, sizeof(int)); 

struct sockaddr_in si_other;
int slen=sizeof(si_other);
char buf[BUFLEN];
char message[BUFLEN];

int p = atoi ( Port.c_str() ) ;

memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;

si_other.sin_port = htons(p);
si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr( IP.c_str() );

strcpy_s ( message , "Hello" ) ;


//send the message
if ( sendto ( s , message , strlen(message) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other , slen ) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf ( "sendto() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError() ) ;
   return ;
}

//receive a reply and print it
memset ( buf , '\0' , BUFLEN ) ;
//try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
if ( recvfrom ( s , buf , BUFLEN , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other , &slen ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
{
    printf("recvfrom() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    return ;
}

struct sockaddr_in localAddress;
int addrlen = sizeof(localAddress) ;

getsockname ( s , (struct sockaddr*)&localAddress , &addrlen ) ;

USHORT LocalPort = localAddress.sin_port ;
IN_ADDR localAddr = localAddress.sin_addr ;

printf("local address: %s\n", inet_ntoa( localAddress.sin_addr));
printf("local port: %d\n", (int) ntohs(localAddress.sin_port));

printf ( "\n******************************************\n\n" ) ;

int pos = 1 ;
CStringA CBuff = CStringA ( buf ) ;

string RemortPort = CBuff.Tokenize ( "-" , pos ) ;
string RemortIp = CBuff.Tokenize ( "-" , pos ) ;


reuse = 1 ;

SOCKET Sock_Reuse = socket ( AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP ) ;

setsockopt( Sock_Reuse , SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,(char*) &reuse, sizeof(int)); // optional, but recommended

struct sockaddr_in sin;
memset(&sin,0,sizeof(sin));
sin.sin_family=AF_INET;
sin.sin_port=htons(LocalPort);
sin.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;

if ( SOCKET_ERROR == connect(Sock_Reuse,(struct sockaddr *)&sin,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)))
{
    printf ( "bind failed %d" , WSAGetLastError() ) ;
}

closesocket ( Sock_Reuse ) ;
closesocket ( s ) ;
WSACleanup ( ) ;
```

}

In the same method I am trying to open the new socket with same port.

Check this Java Code I am trying to do like this in C/C++. It is not Possible ??

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.net.* ;

public class UDPHolePunchingClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // prepare Socket
    DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();

    // prepare Data
    byte[] sendData = "Hello".getBytes();

    // send Data to Server with fix IP (X.X.X.X)
    // Client1 uses port 7070, Client2 uses port 7071
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData,
            sendData.length, InetAddress.getByName("172.24.8.110"), 7070);
    clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

    // receive Data ==> Format:"<IP of other Client>-<Port of other Client>"
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024], 1024);
    clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);

    // Convert Response to IP and Port
    String response = new String(receivePacket.getData());
    String[] splitResponse = response.split("-");
    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(splitResponse[0].substring(1));

    int port = Integer.parseInt(splitResponse[1]);

    // output converted Data for check
    System.out.println("IP: " + ip + " PORT: " + port);

    // close socket and open new socket with SAME localport
    int localPort = clientSocket.getLocalPort();
    clientSocket.close();
    clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(localPort);

    // set Timeout for receiving Data
    clientSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);

    // send 5000 Messages for testing
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {

        // send Message to other client
        sendData = ("Datapacket(" + i + ")").getBytes();
        sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, ip, port);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

        // receive Message from other client
        try {
            receivePacket.setData(new byte[1024]);
            clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            System.out.println("REC: "
                    + new String(receivePacket.getData()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("SERVER TIMED OUT");
        }
    }

    // close connection
    clientSocket.close();
}

}
```

Comment: C and C++ both have no idea what a "socket" is. Which operating system and compiler?

Comment: In UDP, you use a single socket per port. A UDP socket can handle any number of connections.

Comment: Opening multiple sockets on the same local port wouldn't make sense in any context.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode We can set the source port as local port port of some other socket in java.

Comment: The closure is ridiculous. The question is perfectly clear.

Comment: can someone please remove the hold? Otherwise i can't the suggestions and answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to all the commentary, all you have to do is set the socket option `SO_REUSEPORT` prior to the `bind()`.

Comment: I have done this. but where i can set the local port of current socket.

Comment: Err, in the `bind()` call?

Comment: If I use bind call windows throwing some alert.

Comment: @bala That tells jus precisely nothing. **What** alert? Vague statements like that are not acceptable. In any case, if you *don't* use the `bind()` call you can't use *any* specific port, let alone re-use it.

Comment: The main problem with opening two or more UDP sockets on the same port is that when a packet comes in, it is undefined which socket will receive the packet.  It could be just one (any one), or it could be all.  This is assuming unicast.  If on the other hand the sockets are listening for multicast traffic, incoming multicast packets will be delivered to any socket that has joined the multicast group for that packet.

Comment: @Ejp 

When I use `bind ()` call Windows firewall throws some alert, how to bypass that ?

Comment: @dbush Your comment should be addressed to the OP.

Comment: @bala Either instruct the user to accept it or configure a rule in the firewall.

Comment: @bala Please post your code, along with the exact text of any error message you receive when running it, so that we may better assist you.

Comment: @bala It means you, the Original Poster.

Comment: @bala And what's your problem now?

Comment: I need to open the second UDP socket with the first socket's local port.

Comment: It's Working Fine. When I try to bind the new port It's throwing alert now i am trying to bind the already existing port.

Comment: @bala You have to set this option on both sockets. But I don't understand why you're closing a socket and then creating a new one on the same port in your Java code. It's pointless. If you're trying to mirror that behaviour in your C code, don't. Just leave the socket open.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Java code is not in fact opening two sockets on the same port, but closing the first socket then opening a new one on the same port as the one that was closed.  For a UDP socket not in a connected state, that shouldn't be necessary at all.

If you're not changing the port, your C++ code should be able to continue to use the same socket instead of making a new one.  Assuming you want to mirror what the Java code is doing, you shouldn't need to call `connect`.  Just use `sendto` and `recvfrom` to send data back and forth.

Comment: It's not even necessary in the connected state. Just connect it to `null`: that's a disconnect.